# how to merge or inject "@" character in a string including escape characters without definning the string varibale from scratch in C#

Tags: c#, string

hi , I have 2 related questions.

1)suppose we have:

string strMessage="\nHellow\n\nWorld";
console.writeln(strMessage);

---

Result is:

Hellow


World

---

Now if we want to show the string in ***the original format in One Line***
we must redefine the first variable from scratch.

---

string strOrignelMessage=@"\nHellow\n\nWorld"  ;

console.writln(strOrignelMessage);

---

Result is:



\nHellow\n\nWorld --------------------->and everything is ok.

i am wondering is there a way to avoid definning
the new variable(strOrignelMessage) in code for this purpose and just using only
the first string variable(strMessage) and apply some tricks and print it in one line.

at first i tried the following workaround but it makes some bugs.suppose we have:

---

string strMessage="a\aa\nbb\nc\rccc";

string strOrigenalMessage=strMessage.replace("\n","\\n").replace("\r","\\r");

Console.writeln(strOrigenalMessage)

---

result is :aa\nbb\nc\rccc

***notice that befor the first  "\" not printed***.*and now  my second question is:*

2)How we can fix the new problem with single "\"in the string

i hope to entitle this issue correctly and my explanations would be enough,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the compiler has already converted all of your escaped characters in the original string to the characters they represent. After the fact, it is too late to convert them to non-special characters. You can do a search and replace, converting '\n' to literally @"\n", but that is whacky and you're better off defining the string correctly in the first place. If you wanted to escape the backslashes in the first place, why not put an extra backslash character in front of each of them:

Instead of "\n" use "\\n".

Updated in response to your comment:

If the string is coming from user input, you don't need to escape the backslash, because it will be stored as a backslash in the input string. The escape character only works as an escape character in string literals in code (and not preceded by @, which makes them verbatim string literals).

Comment: suppose this string would be passed inside the program for example from user input ,i know the nature of \\ but using @ is a safe way.it seems thati ts impossoble if we want to have an extention method or helper method that converts a string to non escape character version using @. am i right? if this is true, could any one suggest me a method that converts a string to non-escap character version that works correctly?thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want "\n\n\a\a\r\blah" to print as `\n\n\a\a\r\blah` without `@` just replace all `\` with `\\`

`\` is the escaper in a non-verbatim string. So you simply need to escape the escaper, as it were.

Comment: sorry for too late, my computer had been infected terribly .ok could you pls suggest some snippet that replace \ with \\ in the string ,i try many codes but it seems that compiler just doesnt like to understand what we want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both strings, but want to have only one in the code then write the string with @, and construct the other one with Replace(@"\n","\n").

Answer (score 0):

explanations for Anthony Pegram (if i understand u right) and anyone that found it usefull

i think i find my way in question2.

at first ,unfortunately,i thought that the
escape characters limts to \n,\t,\r,\v and
this made me confuesed becouse in my sample string i used \a and \b 
and the compiler behaviuor was not understandable for me.

but finally i found that \a and \b is in 
escape-characters set too.and if u use "\" without escap characters
a compile time error would be raised (its so funny when i think to My mistake again)

pls refers to this usefull msdn article for more info.

[2.4.4.5 String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691090)

and you couldnt replace \ (single\) with \\
becouse fundamentally you couldnt have a (single \) without using
escape-characters after it in a string .so we coudnt write such a string in the code:

string strTest="abc\pwww";  ------> compile time error

and for retriving an inactived escape characters version of a string
we can use simply string.replace method as i used befor.

excuse me for long strory ,thank u all for cooperation.